# Calculate x, y coordinates of rotated line segments to draw on a Canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry

This is less an HTML, CANVAS question and more of a general math question. I posted it here because it's prototyped using CANVAS and is still kind of a general programming question that I thought someone could answer. Here is the basic idea: I want to draw a line 10 pixels thick, but I don't want to use the standard lineTo and set a stroke width. I want to actually draw the border of the line using beginPath and lineTo. The reason being is this is actually for AS3 project and using this method allows us to have a line stroke and fill. So rotating the canvas and things of that nature are out of the question. I just need to figure out how to calculate the proper x, y coordinates for the line.

In the code below is the coordinates for the top of a line. I basically want to take this coordinates, add 10 to the y axis for each one and that will give me the return coordinates for the bottom of the line. Of course, each segment of the line is rotated, so calculating the coordinates for the bottom of the line has proved tricky. I'm hoping someone can help.

Once you run the example code, the issue should be obvious. The line isn't drawn properly. For relatively mild rotations of line segments it seems to work, but as the angle of rotation gets more severe the x, y coordinates are calculated incorrectly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var coords = [
    {x:78,y:183},
    {x:130,y:183},
    {x:237,y:212},
    {x:450,y:213},
    {x:517,y:25},
    {x:664,y:212},
    {x:716,y:212}
];

var coordsBck = [];

for( i = 0; i < coords.length; i++ ) {
    var c1, c2, r;
    c1 = coords[i];

    if( i < coords.length - 1 ) {
        c2 = coords[i + 1];
        r = Math.atan2((c2.y - c1.y),(c2.x - c1.x));
        console.log( c1.x, c1.y, c2.x, c2.y, ( r * 180/Math.PI ));
    }
    else
    {
        r = 00;
    }
    var d = r * 180/Math.PI;    
    var cos = Math.cos( r );
    var sin = Math.sin( r );

    var x = cos * 0 - sin * 10;
    var y = sin * 0 + cos * 10;
    coordsBck.push({x: c1.x + x, y: c1.y + y});
}

while(coordsBck.length > 0 )
{
    coords.push( coordsBck.pop() );
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
for( i = 0; i < coords.length; i++ ) {
    var line = coords[i];
    console.log( i, line.x, line.y );
    if( i == 0 )
    {
        ctx.moveTo( line.x, line.y );
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.lineTo( line.x, line.y );
    }
}
ctx.fill();

function t(o) {
    return "x: " + o.x + ", y: " + o.y;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need end caps. http://jsfiddle.net/xA6kB/1/

```
<doctype !html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var points =
[
    {x: 78, y: 183},
    {x: 130, y: 183},
    {x: 237, y: 212},
    {x: 450, y: 213},
    {x: 517, y: 25},
    {x: 664, y: 212},
    {x: 716, y: 212}
];

var quads = [];
var lineThickness = 10;

// Remove the -1 to create a loop
for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; ++i)
{
    var point = points[i];
    var nextPoint = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
    // Right hand normal with x positive to the right and y positive down
    var normal = {x: -(nextPoint.y - point.y), y: nextPoint.x - point.x};
    // Normalize normal
    var normalLength = Math.sqrt(normal.x * normal.x + normal.y * normal.y);
    normal.x /= normalLength;
    normal.y /= normalLength;

    // A quad has 4 points
    quads.push({x: point.x - lineThickness / 2 * normal.x, y: point.y - lineThickness / 2 * normal.y});
    quads.push({x: nextPoint.x - lineThickness / 2 * normal.x, y: nextPoint.y - lineThickness / 2 * normal.y});
    quads.push({x: nextPoint.x + lineThickness / 2 * normal.x, y: nextPoint.y + lineThickness / 2 * normal.y});
    quads.push({x: point.x + lineThickness / 2 * normal.x, y: point.y + lineThickness / 2 * normal.y});
}

var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < quads.length; i += 4)
{
    context.moveTo(quads[i].x, quads[i].y);
    context.lineTo(quads[i + 1].x, quads[i + 1].y);
    context.lineTo(quads[i + 2].x, quads[i + 2].y);
    context.lineTo(quads[i + 3].x, quads[i + 3].y);
}
context.fill();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do actually need the end caps, but looking at your answer helped me out quite a bit by making me realize I need to treat the line segments a little more like rectangles, which helped in determining the additional coordinates I ended up needing. So thank you. :)

Comment: I didn't end up using this, but it did help me get to where I needed so I'm selecting this as the answer. To see what I came up with, I answered my own question below. Or you can just check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WesleyJohnson/sAaM9/1/

Comment: ho, and since i m working on that those times, would you like to know how to make a smooth joint ??   because you might have noticed that two segments not having same slope have an horrible joint with just rectangle drawing (kind of PS1 looking :=) )

Answer (score 1):

When i have such issues, i usually compute normalized vectors, and 'play' with them.
Say you draw a line from A to B, compute AB vector (ABx=Bx-Ax ; ABy=By-Ay) then i normalize it (...) to get ABN.

Then i compute ABNR, the 90 degree rotation of ABN ( ABNR.x = -ABN.y ; ABNR.y = ABN.x )

Then in your example, say A' and A'' are the points surrounding A, we have the simple A'=A+5*ABNR  and A''= A-5*ABNR  , and as well  B'=B+5*ABNR and B''=B-5*ABNR. 
The rectangle you want to draw is the A'A''B''B' rectangle.

There must be much more optimized way to do this (after all, one can draw a line with only additions), this one is simple and works, it depends on your speed rquirements. You may also optimze the code once you have your formulas working.

Comment: Hi Vincent! I appreciate your answer and I kind of understand what you're getting at, but the math is a little over my head. I think Sirisian basically did what you were implying, but he actually wrote the code out. With your answer explaining the concept and his answer writing it out, it's helped me out a great deal. Thank you!

Comment: too bad i couldn't draw because with a drawing it is soooo obvious.
Glad i could help anyway :=)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up sorting this out after Vincent and Sirisian's answers gave me some ideas. I really appreciate the input guys! Basically, both of those answers made me realized I should be treating the segments like rectangles and that I needed some additional coordinates. I put together a jsfiddle if anyone was in interested.

http://jsfiddle.net/WesleyJohnson/sAaM9/1/

Comment: Thanks mate, you might well have saved me some time with pen and paper working out all this.